# Is there a way to get the icons that are used in Summoner's Rift minimap?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm developing a webapp and it would be awesome if there's a way to find (or extract) the icons (i.e.: turrets, inhibitors, pings, champion circles, nexus, baron, etc.)

Comment: Is it legal to take assets like this without permission? Especially if you are going to be publishing this webapp online for others.

Comment: It's just a draft to plan your tactics or strategies in-game (an online paint with extra tools, sequences or frames, etc.). I believe I mean that this webapp is for educational purposes.

Comment: RIOT has set a precedent that you may use their assets and data so long as your application is available to all players and only monetizes through ads. You should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

All of the game assets are packed into RAF files that can be extracted using this tool:

http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=8597866#post8597866

They tend to be in this folder: C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_game_client\filearchives

There you will find a ton of folders (one for each patch). Content generally resides in the folder of the patch on which it came, or possibly even the patch you installed the game on. Just sort the folders by content size and start from the largest, you will eventually find the right RAF file.

Once you find the files they could be any number of formats. Hopefully they will be png and you will be good to go but some may be dds or something like that. A quick web search of the extension should point you in the direction of a tool that can open that type.

**Option 2:**

Google or Bing Images + Photoshop or GIMP and construct the images on your own.

**Option 3:**

Some sites like lolking or lolpro have a number of the assets already extracted or chopped up, you can always grab them from these sites.

Chances are a combination of the above will get you everything you need asset wise. If you need any game statistics RIOT has made them available through this API: https://developer.riotgames.com/